Parskip produces different whitespace after section heading and bibliography heading in scrbook document
I am writing a document that uses the scrbook  documentclass. This document also contains a bibliography generated using biblatex with biber as backend. I want the bibliography to have a section heading and being called 'References', so I use:
\printbibliography[
        title={References}, % Change title from bibliography to references
        heading=subbibnumbered  % Number the reference section
    ]

In the compiled document, the spacing between the chapter section headings seems consistent throughout the document, except for the heading of the bibliography. Somehow, the first line of the bibliography seems to be shifted upwards. I have tried figuring out why this is happening, and it seems to be related to the parskip package. If I disable this package, the spacing does not occur. If I enable it, it does occur. Similarly, if I directly set parskip when loading the scrbook class (\documentclass[10pt, parskip=full]{scrbook], the spacing also changes. I have rendered the different outputs:

scrbook + biblatex[backend=biber] + parskip



scrbook + biblatex[backend=biber]



scrbook[parskip=full] + biblatex[backend=biber]


As the images show, only scrbook + biblatex[backend=biber] without parskip renders the expected result. I have tried ways to correct it, and it seems like adding \AtBeginBibliography{\vspace*{0.5\parskip}} somehow corrects it:

scrbook[parskip=full] + biblatex[backend=biber] + parskip + AtBeginBibliography{vspace*{0.5\parskip}}


I am happy that I was able to correct it this way, but am not sure if the correction is robust (e.g. when I change font or font size). Is this the proper way to handle it or is there more to it?

MWE
bibliography: testrefs.bib
@article{testref,
    author  = "John Doe",
    title   = "Test reference",
    year    = "2024",
    journal = "NA",
    volume  = "1",
    number  = "1",
    pages   = "1-2"
}

Latex code
Adjust where indicated for different examples
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
%\documentclass[10pt, paaskip=full]{scrbook} % Enable to test parskip from scrbook

\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage}  % Every section starts on new page

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testrefs.bib}

\usepackage{parskip}  % enable or disable for different tests

\usepackage{geometry}  % for easy comparison of whitespace between pages make them small
\geometry{
    papersize={50mm,50mm,},
    inner=5mm,
    outer=5mm,
    top=5mm,
    bottom=5mm
}

%\AtBeginBibliography{\vspace*{0.5\parskip}}  % Enable for fix. Somehow the bibliography title seems to get only 0.5\parskip


\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}

    \section{section 1}
    scrbook + biblatex(biber) + parskip

    \printbibliography[
        title={References}, % Change title from bibliography to references
        heading=subbibnumbered  % Number the reference section
    ]
\end{document}



don't use parskip package with koma script, as you show, it has it's built in functionality to control paragraph spacing.

Welcome to TeX.SE!
